# Key Scheduling of the International Data Encryption Algorithm (IDEA)

Tags: encryption, key-schedule, idea

How is key scheduling done in the International Data Encryption Algorithm (IDEA). I did some research, but to no avail.

I could not understand this statement from [Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Data_Encryption_Algorithm):

> **...further groups of eight keys are created by rotating the main key left 25 bits between each group of eight."**

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: here's a java applet that shows actual calculations. Hopefully its helpful. The site is in German, but it shouldnt matter: http://www.informationsuebertragung.ch/indexAlgorithmen.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the corresponding [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=8BDAEB1644BEF66E7F56E454D79EA1FF?doi=10.1.1.14.3451&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

The key is a 128-bit string $K$. The round keys for round $r=1,...,8$ are derived as follows:

- take the version of $K$ cyclically rotated to the left $25\cdot r$ times;
- split the string obtained into eight substrings and call them $Z_1^{(r)}$, ..., $Z_8^{(r)}$.

The keys $Z_7^{(r)}$ and $Z_8^{(r)}$ are never used. The subkeys $Z_1^{(9)}$, ..., $Z_4^{(9)}$ are used to mask the output.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a key we 128 bit master key:0110101010101 up to 128.
1 key= 16 bit chunks so in this case we generate 8 keys of 16 bits.
but one thing the most important while generating keys when we reach to 25th bit means from start to 25 bit then we do LS-25.

1101 Ls-1= 1011 only one left bit is shift to right.
1101 ls-2= 0111 two bits are shift to right.
So in case of ls-25 ...25 bits are shift to right.

At last we to complete 7 rounds to finish the process.

Comment: "To generate a key we 128 bit master key" --> we what?

Comment: "At last we to complete"  -->  what does "we to" mean?